# login with twitter in ionic cordova not working using $cordovaOauth.twitter

Tags: cordova, twitter, oauth, ionic-framework

I want to integrate twitter login to validate user in my hybrid application using Cordova Oauth plugin, followed the instruction from [ngcordova oauth](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/).

And demonstration steps from [Here](http://blog.ionic.io/oauth-ionic-ngcordova/), as there given that about callback URIs must point to localhost/callback otherwise, the login flow will not complete but in when I am going to set in Apps management its giving

> *Error The client application failed validation: Not a valid URL format*

I have console the return response but not getting any alert, below code I am using

```
$scope.twitterLogin = function() {
$cordovaOauth.twitter("6VjHDXXXXXXXXXXXX", "erN45XbC3b35XXXXXXXXXXXX").then(function(result) {
            alert('ok111');
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        }, function(error) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
}
```

Comment: What's the output of the error? Could you please add it to your question?

Comment: Thanks mhx, its failing in twitter authorization when I debugged ng-cordova.min.js twitter function as I have provided valid keys and not getting any kind of alert from success or error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have created a working twitterExample and uploaded in [github](https://github.com/Sabharshin/ionic_twitter_login/tree/master). Please take a 
look

Have added the steps below for quick reference.

Pre-requisites
Create a twitter app and get Consumer Key (API Key) and Consumer Secret (API Secret).

Steps
1) Create a project 
2) cd into the project
3) Add the required platform(s)
4) Download "ng-cordova.min.js" and add to js folder
5) Add the "ng-cordova.min.js" path in "index.html" file just above "cordova.js" path
6) Add the dependancy "ngCordova" in "app.js" angular module
7) Add the plugin "cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git" from terminal
8) Download the "sha1.js" file and add to js folder
9) Add the "sha1.js" path in index file
10) Type "bower install ng-cordova-oauth -S" from terminal
11) Add the "ng-cordova-oauth" file path to index file
12) Include "ngCordovaOauth" dependancy in "app.js" angular module
13) Add the "$cordovaOauth" to the controller which is using twitter login function
14) Add the controller and ng-click in index.html
15) Add the twitter login function in the controller as show in the app.js (Please replace the api_key and api_secret with your twitter app details)

Thanks to Nic Raboy for the plugin and blog.

Comment: Thanks sab arish, I will implement and get back

Comment: @ Sab Arish, what about oauth_callback=http://localhost/callback setting from twitter app manager as in my case it giving above error I pasted, does is affect in working or it is optional. I tried sample twitterExample app from github but is showing  first alert twitterlogin function got called and then get loading popup and nothing go ahead

Comment: I can share my twitter keys if you have time to test in your sample app as no luck for me

Comment: Thanks Sab Arish, now it is working thanks again for your efforts

Comment: Glad it worked. Please post the steps with which you solved the localhost/callback issue, will be helpful for other users as well.

Comment: In Twitter Application Management setting page there is check box to Enable Callback Locking, we need to unchecked it to override callback url from given url in oauth twitter function.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment to my plugin and blog :-)

Comment: @AbsarHasan I do have the "Enable Callback Locking ..." option unchecked, but for localhost twitter says: The client application failed validation: Not a valid URL format. Is that step exclusively necessary for the $cordovaOauth to work?

Comment: @Alexander I did that only and app was working fine, may be some other issue in your case

Comment: Here is a tutorial which shows how to [implement Twitter Login in Ionic](http://codehandbook.org/twitter-login-in-ionic-hybrid-mobile-app/)

Comment: "I tried sample twitterExample app from github but is showing first alert twitterlogin function got called and then get loading popup and nothing go ahead" I have de the same situation, I replaced the api key and api secret and I changed my callback to this http://127.0.0.1:8100/callback, what else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

i used http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback when creating the twitter application and it worked