# twitter Login using ngCordova Plugin in ionic

Tags: cordova, twitter, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I am new in Ionic, i am trying to login with twitter,
I am using ngCordova, i have following these steps,
but i am not getting any response, even now showing any login screen for twitter in app.

```
 $scope.twitterLogin = function() {
 $cordovaOauth.twitter("6VjHDXXXXXXXXXXXX", "erN45XbC3b35XXXXXXXXXXXX").then(function(result) {
        alert('test');
        alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    }, function(error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

[login with twitter in ionic cordova not working using $cordovaOauth.twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852613/login-with-twitter-in-ionic-cordova-not-working-using-cordovaoauth-twitter)

https://github.com/Sabharshin/ionic_twitter_login/tree/master

I have read and followed above tutorials.

Thanks

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: How did it go? did you manage to connect with twitter?