# Twitter login from PhoneGap application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, twitter, phonegap-plugins

I want to implement Twitter login for my PhoneGap application.
I googled few of the available Twitter Plugins for PhoneGap but nothing fits my requirements.

The Twitter plugin that is listed as official PhoneGap plugin requires creating account on [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/twitter-login), which I don't prefer. 
https://github.com/ManifestWebDesign/twitter-connect-plugin

Also one method suggests to use inAppBrowser: 
http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms

Where we need to have this HTML Page dependency, and also not very clear how it works. (Above links provides details about using ChildBrowser but I don't know How to change it for using inAppBrowser)

In below plugin it supports only iOS no Android:
https://github.com/etiennea/phonegap-twitter-plugin

So basically what is the best way for providing login using Twitter for PhoneGap based app which is targeted to run on iOS and Android platforms.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using Cordova use $cordovaOauth for social login

See my post's answer [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852613/login-with-twitter-in-ionic-cordova-not-working-using-cordovaoauth-twitter) to get step by step solution. I used [$cordovaOauth plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/oauth/) and it worked for me.

```
$scope.twitterLogin = function () {
$cordovaOauth.twitter("6VjHDXXXXXXXXXXXX", "erN45XbC3b35XXXXXXXXXXXX").then(function (result) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
}, function (error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

}

Comment: Is your requirement different than this?

Comment: Actually I am not comfortable in using third party JS libraries and code. I am ok with PhoneGap plugin supported for iOS and Android. I am planning to use method specified in link ----> http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms

Comment: ok, but if you are using Cordova  $cordovaOauth plugin is easy to use

Comment: There are few JS files that we need use "sha1.js", and I am not feeing comfortable using these files. can we avoid using these files.

Comment: To use Twitter in your project, you must have the open source library, jsSHA, included in your project. This is because Twitter requires request signing using HMAC-SHA1, not natively found in JavaScript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121336/discussion-between-absar-hasan-and-a-user).